# Send custom GATT characteristics using HM-10 (actually a CC2541)

Tags: bluetooth-low-energy

Short question - how do I send data as GATT characteristics from a peripheral BLE device (Android UNO + HM-10) to a central device (i.e. an android smartphone?)

---

I'm working on a BLE peripheral as a learning project right now - I'm using an Arduino Uno and an HM-10. It's going well so far - sensors are working and I can send this data from the Arduino Uno to Android using an HM-10 BLE module (actually a CC2541 clone) on the standard service and characteristic for this device:

- Service UUID: 0000**ffe0**-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
- Characteristic: UUID: 0000**ffe1**-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb

Working in this way the HM-10 emulates a traditional bluetooth serial connection. All good so far!

What I would now like to do is send the data using accepted GATT services and characteristics. For example lets say I would like to use the Running Speed and Cadence service to send my data in a way that can be viewed by any compatible app. I would need to change the service to 0x1814 and the characteristics to:

- Cadence: 0x27A8
- Velocity: 0x27A6
- Gradient: 0x2763

I believe I could do this by using the AT commands:

- AT+UUID0x1814
- AT+CHAR0x2763

I think I'm OK with all of this so far, but what I cannot find guidance on is how to define multiple characteristics, and how to send my sensor data to my central device as GATT characteristics.

For example my speed is 10kmh-1 and my cadence is 80 - how do I specify the GATT characteristics for this and notify the central device when they change? Also bonus question - can I include an additional characteristic for gradient?

I've thoroughly searched but cannot find anything on this. Thanks!

Comment: This has been edited to remove the arduino tag, but if any respondents could keep in mind that I'm working in the Arduino IDE I'd appreciate it :) I'm new to this and likely to be confused easily! haha.

Answer (score 2):

AT+NOTI unfortunately is not the correct command. The manual states:

> AT+NOTI[P1]
>
> If this value is set to 1, when link ESTABLISHED or LOSTED module will send
> OK+CONN or OK+LOST string through UART.

I believe, it's not possible to do what you want. I've been searching my whole day, but there is only this one custom characteristics, and you can change only the short UUID. I found no way to get data from other UUIDs in Central mode.

Here is some more info: [BLECentral - HM-10 BLE Module](http://blog.blecentral.com/2015/05/05/hm-10-peripheral/)

Edit: With new Firmware version > V546, there is a possibility to use 128 Bit UUIds. A readme + the needed software is located here: [jnhuamao Website](http://www.jnhuamao.cn/bluetooth40_en.zip).
And V605 states:

[image: hm-10 readme]

Unfortunately, I did not succeed to update the Firmware yet.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for `AT+NOTI`. Check the datasheet for specifics, but *notify* is what pushes from slave to master.